# share eclim -friendly .vimrc

Tags: vim, eclim

I am trying to to use eclim for my daily development requirements. My .vimrc has some issues preventing few functionalities like code completion etc.

It would be great if anyone using **eclim** regularly share your **.vimrc**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find [my vim setup](https://github.com/pydave/daveconfig/tree/master/multi/vim) on github. I use eclim to do Android development.

See [visualstudioinvoke.vim](https://github.com/pydave/daveconfig/blob/master/multi/vim/.vim/visualstudioinvoke.vim) for how I launch Vim from eclim. This isn't necessary, but it's useful to start at the current line in the current file. It also sets up my eclim menu, bindings, and settings.

It's best to start the eclim server (by opening the "Eclim" eclipse tab) **before** you start gvim.

I have eclim's code completion mapped to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Space</kbd>.

You won't get any code completion for classes that aren't in the scope of the current file. To import, I have a menu option under Eclim > ImportMissing.

---

However, my vimrc might be pretty alien to you, so you might be better served whittling down your vimrc until you figure out what's breaking things. The default map for completions is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>u</kbd>. You can use `:verb map <C-x>` to search for maps that start the same way and it will show you where they're defined.

If you use [SuperTab](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1643), try disabling it. SuperTab and eclim are both maintained by
Eric Van Dewoestine so they should be compatible, but you may have a SuperTab configuration problem.

You could also try updating all of your plugins.